# Podman gives warning >Failed to decode the keys ["configmaps"] from "/home/theuser/.config/containers/containers.conf<

Tags: linux, ubuntu, podman

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and have the following version of podman (`podman version`):

```bash
Version:      3.4.4
API Version:  3.4.4
Go Version:   go1.18.1
Built:        Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

But invoking virtually any command in podman gives me these errors:

```bash
$ podman version
WARN[0000] Failed to decode the keys ["configmaps"] from "/home/theuser/.config/containers/containers.conf". 
WARN[0000] Failed to decode the keys ["configmaps"] from "/home/theuser/.config/containers/containers.conf". 
WARN[0000] Failed to decode the keys ["configmaps"] from "/home/theuser/.config/containers/containers.conf". 
WARN[0000] Failed to decode the keys ["configmaps"] from "/home/theuser/.config/containers/containers.conf". 
WARN[0000] Error validating CNI config file /home/theuser/.config/cni/net.d/gitea-net.conflist: [plugin bridge does not support config version "1.0.0" plugin portmap does not support config version "1.0.0" plugin firewall does not support config version "1.0.0" plugin tuning does not support config version "1.0.0"]
```

What can I do against these warning? The content of my `containers.conf` file is as follows:

```
[containers]
  log_size_max = -1
  pids_limit = 2048
  userns_size = 65536

[engine]
  num_locks = 2048
  stop_timeout = 10

[machine]

[network]

[secrets]

[configmaps]
```

Note that there are no configurations for `configmaps` yet.

Comment: It's probably not a known/valid section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get rid of the warnings after I've removed the `configmaps` section from my `containers.conf` file.

I've got inspiration from @Daniel B's comment and from [this explanation](https://github.com/containers/common/blob/main/docs/containers.conf.5.md) in containers' github: there is simply no such section in the conf file.